# Developing iOS jailbreak application With theos

Tags: ios, makefile, jailbreak, theos

> Lewis:helloworld lewis$ make
>
> Making all for bundle HelloWorld...
>
> Copying resource directories into the bundle wrapper...
>
> Compiling HelloWorldController.m...
>
> Linking bundle HelloWorld...
>
> Stripping HelloWorld...
>
> Signing HelloWorld...
>
> /bin/sh: ldid: command not found

I already downloaded ldid to $THEOS/opt/theos/bin.

Why does the make command output "ldid: command not found"

Comment: Put it in `/usr/bin/`, perhaps?

Comment: Type `echo $PATH` in the console, and share the output with us.

Comment: Did you set the right permissions? You have to type `chmod +x ~/path/to.your/ldid`. For more informations about THEOS, check this website http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools/

Answer (score 2):

Download ldid to /usr/bin/
and make sure you `chmod +x /usr/bin/ldid`